# Как сделать неактивными все ТАБы в cbpFWTabs.js

Tags: javascript, html5

Здравствуйте.

Как сделать неактивными все TABы в cbpFWTabs.js,чтобы юзер только при нажатии таба увидел разворачивающийся контент.

Пример кода https://codepen.io/donysukardi/pen/KwgXVr

```
  <svg class="hidden">
        <defs>
            <path id="tabshape" d="M80,60C34,53.5,64.417,0,0,0v60H80z"></path>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Top Navigation -->
        <div class="codrops-top clearfix">
            <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-prev" href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PagePreloadingEffect/"><span>Previous Demo</span></a>
            <span class="right"><a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-drop" href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=19559"><span>Back to the Codrops Article</span></a></span>
        </div>
        <header class="codrops-header">
            <h1>Tab Styles Inspiration <span>A small collection of styles for tabs</span></h1>
            <p class="support">Your browser does not support <strong>flexbox</strong>! <br>Please view this demo with a <strong>modern browser</strong>.</p>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-bar">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-bar-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-bar-2" class="icon icon-box"><span>Archive</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-bar-3" class="icon icon-display"><span>Analytics</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-bar-4" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-bar-5" class="icon icon-tools"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-bar-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-bar-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-bar-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-bar-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-bar-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-iconbox">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-iconbox-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconbox-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconbox-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconbox-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconbox-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-iconbox-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconbox-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconbox-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconbox-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconbox-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-underline">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-underline-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-underline-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-underline-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-underline-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-underline-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-underline-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-underline-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-underline-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-underline-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-underline-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-linetriangle">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-linetriangle-1"><span>All Products</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linetriangle-2"><span>Electronics</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linetriangle-3"><span>Clothing</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linetriangle-4"><span>Multimedia</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linetriangle-5"><span>Toys</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-linetriangle-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linetriangle-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linetriangle-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linetriangle-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linetriangle-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-topline">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-topline-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-topline-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-iconfall">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-iconfall-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconfall-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconfall-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconfall-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconfall-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-iconfall-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconfall-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconfall-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconfall-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-iconfall-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
            <p>Re-created from <a href="http://vintageproductions.eu/grid/interactivity/">Vintage Productions</a></p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-linemove">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-linemove-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linemove-2" class="icon icon-box"><span>Archive</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linemove-3" class="icon icon-display"><span>Analytics</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linemove-4" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linemove-5" class="icon icon-tools"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-linemove-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linemove-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linemove-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linemove-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linemove-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-line">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-line-1"><span>Our Controls</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-line-2"><span>Sony Playstation 4</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-line-3"><span>Microsoft Xbox One</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-line-4"><span>Nintendo Wii U</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-line-5"><span>Microconsoles</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-line-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-line-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-line-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-line-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-line-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-circle">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-circle-1" class="icon icon-plug"><span>Connect</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circle-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Gifts</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circle-3" class="icon icon-box"><span>Boxes</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circle-4" class="icon icon-date"><span>Prints</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circle-5" class="icon icon-plane"><span>Fun</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-circle-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circle-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circle-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circle-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circle-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-shape">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current">
                            <a href="#section-shape-1">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <span>Home</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#section-shape-2">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <span>Design</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#section-shape-3">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <span>Work</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#section-shape-4">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <span>Portfolio</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#section-shape-5">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <span>Contact</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-shape-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-shape-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-shape-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-shape-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-shape-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-linebox">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-linebox-5"><span>Airline</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linebox-4"><span>Schedule</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linebox-2"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linebox-3"><span>Drinks</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-linebox-5"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-linebox-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linebox-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linebox-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linebox-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-linebox-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-flip">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-flip-5" class="icon icon-plane"><span>Airline</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-flip-4" class="icon icon-date"><span>Schedule</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-flip-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-flip-3" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Drinks</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-flip-5" class="icon icon-tools"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-flip-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-flip-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-flip-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-flip-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-flip-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-circlefill">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-circlefill-1" class="icon icon-plug"><span>Connect</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circlefill-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Gifts</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circlefill-3" class="icon icon-box"><span>Boxes</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circlefill-4" class="icon icon-date"><span>Prints</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-circlefill-5" class="icon icon-plane"><span>Fun</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-circlefill-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circlefill-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circlefill-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circlefill-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-circlefill-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-tzoid">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-tzoid-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-tzoid-2" class="icon icon-box"><span>Archive</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-tzoid-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-tzoid-4" class="icon icon-display"><span>Analytics</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-tzoid-5" class="icon icon-tools"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-tzoid-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-tzoid-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-tzoid-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-tzoid-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-tzoid-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
            <p>Technique from <a href="http://vintageproductions.eu/grid/interactivity/">Slanted tabs with CSS 3D transforms</a> by Lea Verou</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-fillup">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-current"><a href="#section-fillup-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-fillup-1" class="content-current"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-fillup-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-fillup-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-fillup-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-fillup-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
        <!-- Related demos -->
        <section class="related">
            <p>If you enjoyed this demo you might also like:</p>
            <a href="http://tympanus.net/Development/ArrowNavigationStyles/">
                <img src="img/relatedposts/ArrowNavigationEffects-300x162.png">
                <h3>Arrow Navigation Styles</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="http://tympanus.net/Development/DotNavigationStyles/">
                <img src="img/relatedposts/DotNavigationStyles-300x162.png">
                <h3>Dot Navigation Styles</h3>
            </a>
        </section>
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/cbpFWTabs.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {

            [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
                new CBPFWTabs( el );
            });

        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Да, вопрос похож, но я немного ошибся с созданием прошлого вопроса, т.к. я указал совсем другой модуль.

Comment: Кто-то может подсказать, как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: В самом коде _cbpFWTabs_ если не задан стартовая вкладка всегда выбирается первая. Изменить это поведение, можно только отредактировав исходники

Comment: Долго и мучительно это делать?

Comment: нет, не долго и не мучительно

Comment: Сможете "подшаманить"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом коде cbpFWTabs если не задан стартовая вкладка всегда выбирается первая. Изменить это поведение, можно только отредактировав исходники.

Проблема кроется в методе `_show`, который при инициализации вызывается без параметров.

Один из вариантов решения - добавить в код метода следующую проверку

```
CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function( idx ) {
    if( this.current >= 0 ) {
        this.tabs[ this.current ].className = this.items[ this.current ].className = '';
    }
    if(idx === undefined) return; // если параметр не задан - ничего не делаем 
...
```

**[Пример работы на CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrjWLg)**